# removing "+" signs from an email address with angularJS and Reg Exp

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, web

I was tasked with making email address with a "+" sign invalid for registry. I'm new to regex and my research into it led me to believe it's best to state what you want in a valid input and not what you don't want. I used RegexBuddy's simplified RFC 2822 and removed the plus signs from it, to get that expression:

```
       [a-z0-9!#$%&'*/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

while passing RB's test feature (i.e. invalidating "aaa+aa@gmail.com"), it fails to correctly invalidate same input when I use the same expression as the **ng-pattern**

Comment: Don't do that; `+` is perfectly valid.

Comment: not saying it isn't.. but if I have to? @SLaks

Comment: You want to replace `+` or test if email contains `+` ?

Comment: [Validating emails with a regex is hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address); validating a subset of email addresses with a regex you're trying to write yourself is harder. If you're sole requirement is "should not contain a +" write a solution that does that, and only that.

Answer (score 0):

**A quick solution**

**To remove + symbol**

```
"aaa+aa@gmail.com".replace(/\+/g,''); // -> aaaaa@gmail.com
```

**To validate**

```
var email = "aaa+aa@gmail.com";
var valid = email.match(/\+/g) ? false : true;
if(valid) {
  console.log("Email Id doesn't contain +");
} else {
  console.log("Email Id contains + Invalid");
}
```

Comment: I very much doubt the OP actually wants to remove the plus. As stated in the question, the OP wants to validate the address, which your answer is not doing.

Comment: Updated the code to invalidate email with '+' symbol

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match if email contains `+` :

```
if (/\+/im.test(email)) {
    alert("INVALID " + email );
} else {
    alert("VALID " + email);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/6gWvJ/3/

Regex to replace the `+` from email address:

```
email = email.replace(/\+/, "");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/7VFNA/2/